# ImageTemplateId for OSReload in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm implementing OSreload with java client.

```
Guest.Service gService = Guest.service(client, 22075687L);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setImageTemplateId(imageTemplateId); // imageTemplateId??
gService.reloadOperatingSystem("FORCE", config);
```

How can I get a ImageTemplate ID? 
To select OS, I am using "packageService" to get a price and OS description, but I can't find its imageTemplate Id.

[image: OSReload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to do an OS reload, **you can use an image template or priceId**. In the screen that you showed, [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) uses a price (These are items offered by SoftLayer), so it doesn't have an ImageTemplateId